# How to add multiple templates in a Docusign Powewrform

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I am using Demo account for testing and I have prod account as well.

I want to achieve one functionality as mentioned below:

I have four documents A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf and D.pdf.

I want to add these documents to docusign as separate - separate templates i.e. 4 documents means 4 templates.

Only Template A will have Signer(I need to send only this document to end user once it is signed) rest of templates will not have signers.

I want to use these 4 templates in powerforms(Since I need to get sign on each document but has to send document A.pdf to end user), but issue is I can't use all 4 templates in a single powerform.

Docusign does not have ability to add more than one template.

Can you suggest me; how to achieve it in docusign

Answer (score 0):

PowerForms are a 1:1 ratio of PowerForm:templates. I would recommend creating one template with the 4 documents (A,B,C, and D all included).

Comment: Hi Louis, that I am already doing but I need to send only one document to end user once document is signed, not all documents. So if I use all 4 documents in a single template(Currently I am doing this) then all 4 docs will be sent to end user instead of single document How can we send single document ?

Comment: I do not believe you can achieve the ask here using out of the box DocuSign functionality. IMO you would need to download the single document using the API, and generate an email to the signer yourself. Working within the means of what DocuSign offers, it would generate an email with all the documents that the signer had visibility to during signing.